# Use DataGrid in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, datagrid

I have recently started working with `Xamarin Forms` for developing `Android / iOS` applications. One of the requests for the application I am working on was to provide the user an interface for viewing some data (from a **database**) in a tabular form, with the possibility of editing it. As I had worked with `Windows Forms`, my first approach was to use a `DataGridView` - like control, but it doesn't seem to be a straight forward way of using it. I have tried the version provided by **Ebubekir Akgul** (from [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-datagrid/) tutorial) but so far I didn't manage to provide the editing feature, but the data is displayed in read-only format. The code I used for populating the Grid is provided here:

```
//XAML
            <dg:DataGrid x:Name="dgSample">
                <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Name" PropertyName="Name"/>
                    <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Age" PropertyName="Age"/>
                </dg:DataGrid.Columns>

                <dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
                    <dg:PaletteCollection>
                        <Color>#F2F2F2</Color>
                        <Color>#FFFFFF</Color>
                    </dg:PaletteCollection>
                </dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
            </dg:DataGrid>

//C#
            dgSample.ItemsSource = mySampleList;
```

For simplicity, the columns' names and count in the grid were modified. The list contains objects with public properties (so in this case, a Person class with public Age and Name properties) as I read having private fields might not allow the edit (unfortunately I cannot find the site where I read this anymore), so for practicing purposes I've set them all on public, but still no success.

I have also tried other `DataGrid` implementations (such as the one provided by **Syncfusion**), but the licenses they require for it in order to be used are not something I am provided by my superiors.

My question is what would be the best approach for displaying the data in tabular form and enabling the editing feature. If the current approach allows me to do so, I'd like to know what I am missing from accessing this feature.

If there is anything else I have to share, please let me know and I will update the question. Have a nice day!

Edit: [here](https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid) is the GitHub repo of the `DataGrid` package.

Comment: which datagrid component are you using?  Have you read the docs to see if it supports editing?

Comment: @Jason As far as I managed to read through the documentation and his examples, it doesn't seem to be possible (the link to the GitHub repo is in the question now). I will have a better look over it tomorrow, just to make sure. If there is no such feature for this approach, could you recommend another one?

Comment: No idea, there are many variations of DataGrid available, but this is a very complex thing to do and it wouldn't surprise me if none of the free ones supported editing.  If this is critical for your app you may need to purchase a license for a commercial solution

Comment: I would just use a custom control made with Grid, when one would click on cell either insert a focused Entry inside cell or pop an editor popup based on rg.plugin popup nuget

Comment: @NickKovalsky I guess that would be the best way of solving it, at least for the moment. After I manage to implement it, I will comeback and post the code for that as an answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use ListView?

[ListView documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/)

I think this component you help you, just using the documentation and some examples in github/yotube you can find out everything you need.

Indicated:

[Collapse list](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOTpJG98EMA&ab_channel=TipsByAnil)

[MVVM Delete](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZxjofHU0J0&ab_channel=XamarinGuy)

[Item click event](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMRg0P2f9N4&ab_channel=CarsandCode)

I hope these can help you in your projects